# I am returning to a company, but I started another company before leaving this one. Is that okay?

Tags: hiring-process, human-resources, india

I had joined a company and resigned within 4months and served my notice period for a month, after my resignation I joined a new company as a fresher a day prior to my last working day in my previous company. Now I will be rejoining the same company. Will this date of last working day in previous company and date of joining next company affect my rejoining? Is it fine to rejoin ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: How did you do that? How could you have been at two locations at once? Did you pretend to be sick on that day? Did you use up an unusued vacation day?

Comment: My both companies were in the same location and I had used comp off for one day from previous organisation to join the new company .

Answer (score 1):

> Will this date of last working day in previous company and date of joining next company affect my rejoining?

This is a matter of what the company decides, and we cannot help you here.

> Is it fine to rejoin ?

As long as you left on good terms, why not? I know a guy who left in less than good terms (read: words were said, the kind one does not usually find in dictionaries), and after some negotiation, he was accepted when he returned and everything was fine.

Of course, the company might have a different point of view, and only they know (hopefully) what they will do.

Comment: Thank you , I had completed all the formalities before leaving without any issues and since I was joing as fresher to new company I didn't inform my previous organisation, also I have informed this date overlap issue with the HR assigned to me now. Hope everything goes fine :)